# 2017 Golf - Remove rear external door handle

Tags: vw, golf, door-handle

I've watched a lot of videos on how to remove the rear, external door handle on VW's (Golfs, Jettas, Tiguans, Passats), but it's not as easy to see what to do with the hook tool to pull the lever.

Here's a good example video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ia5z55yXSro

Here's the manual version: http://workshop-manuals.com/volkswagen/golf-mk6/body/general_body_repairs_exterior/front_door_central_locking/door_components/removing_and_installing_cover_cap_(without_lock_cylinder)/removing/

There's a hole around the corner from (perpendicular to) the handle, where a hook-like tool is used to disengage a lever. When I shine a light in the hole, it's doesn't look like there's a lever like in the videos.

Does anyone know how to do this for the 2017 Golf?

Comment: Welcome to this Stack. The video seems pretty straight forward. I don't think you're going to be able to see what you need to through the hole, but rather you're going to have to feel your way around with the hook.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I've definitely felt around in there, and it seems like the design of the mechanism has changed. I've even looked up the parts involved in the mechanism, but can't find a good picture.

Comment: There's still a hole there where it shows it in the video?

Comment: Yes, the hole is there with the sticker that covers it. I think if someone could describe a little bit about what angle to put the tool, it would help a lot. I edited the question to include a link to the manual I found for this task.